Invariants of tuples of matrices under $\mathrm{GL}(p)\otimes \mathrm{GL}(q) \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(n)$?
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Consider $\GL(n)$ over some field of characteristic zero (I'm thinking of either the rationals, reals or complexes) and the subgroup $\GL(p)\otimes \GL(q)$ which embeds irreducibly into $\GL(n)$.
It is known that the diagonal conjugation action of $g\in \GL(n)$ on $d$-tuples of matrices $(X_1,\ldots,X_d)\mapsto (gX_1g^{-1},\dotsc,gX_dg^{-1})$ results in a ring of invariants generated by $\operatorname{Tr}(X_{i_1}\cdots X_{i_k})$ for $i_j\in \{1,\dotsc,d\}$.
Similarly, it is known when the group is the orthogonal or symplectic group.

Question: Is there some known result when the group is $\GL(p)\otimes \GL(q)$ (in its diagonal action on the tuples, by conjugation)? Specifically, I'm interested in the lowest dimensional non-trivial case, i.e. when $p=q=2$ and $n=4$.

As far as I understand the question is unfeasible to answer (computationally) when $G$ is some generic reductive group. However I would expect that this can be answered thanks to the tensor product structure and also assuming that both $p$ and $q$ are small.
I'm quite new to invariant theory so I'm not fully familiar with all classical results. Also, I have found a possible relevant question on MO: Invariant polynomials for a product of algebraic groups.

For $p=q=2$, $GL(p) \times GL(q)$ is the same as the product of $SO(4)$ with the group of scalars. Since scalars are irrelevant for conjugation (as you point out), this shows the $GL(4)$-invariants are the same as the $SO(4)$-invariants. The $SO(4)$-invariants will be a module over the $O(4)$-invariants of generic rank at most $2$ and can probably be computed this way.

Under conjugation constants are irrelevant, what do you mean that no nonconstant invariants? For d=1 under GL(n) for instance you get Tr(X^k) as invariants.

I have edited the question to make it clearer what action I'm considering.

@AnotherUser I misunderstood. I have edited to leave only the part of my answer that is still relevant.

What do you mean that the $\mathrm{SO}(4)$-invariants will be a module over the $\mathrm{O}(4)$-invariants? As I am new to invariant theory I'm not sure what kind of action I should consider here, as well as what you mean by "rank" of a module/action. A reference would also be fine. Thanks

@AnotherUser Both invariants form rings and the $O(4)$ invariants are clearly a subring of the $SO(4)$-invariants. Every ring is a module over its subalgebras. These rings are integral domains, so we can tensor the ring of $SO(4)$ invariants with the field of fractions of the ring of $O(4)$-invariants to obtain a vector space, and by rank I mean the dimension of this vector space.

I understand the relationship between the two rings. What do you mean by tensor the $SO(4)$-ring with the $O(4)$-field? Does the dimension of this vector space being at most 2 mean that there are at most 2 more $SO(4)$ independent invariants than $O(4)$ invariants?

@AnotherUser By tensor a ring with a field, I mean a tensor product $A \otimes_B C$ where $B$ is a subring of $A$ and $C$. There cannot be any more $SO(4)$ independent invariants if you mean algebraically independent invariants, since every $SO(4)$-invariant will satisfy an algebraic equation of degree $2$ whose coefficients are $O(4)$-invariants.

I see, although I'm not sure what that tensor product "looks like". Do you have a reference where I could look up (some of) the details? Regarding independent invariance, I meant that you could build a generating set for $SO(4)$ of size 2 larger than the given "canonical" generating set for $O(4)$. I guess now that that is not the case.
